# I want to move from Windows 10

Tags: drivers

So I'm interested in making the move from Windows 10 to Ubuntu. I've got it running as a VM at the moment but would really like to use it as my primary OS and run Windows as a VM instead.

My only worry is drivers - I have a Dell XPS 13 9343. I think it's got the 5th gen i7. 8GB RAM. If I do a clean install of Ubuntu it's likely not going to have all my drivers and most likely my WiFi driver. What's the solution? I'm pressuming pre-download the required driver for Linux and whack it on a USB for when Ubuntu is loaded and then install? Where from?

Please help me.

Comment: [Dell  XPS 13 9343](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201410-15913/) is a certified Ubuntu Laptop

Comment: I've installed Ubuntu on anything from a dell chromebook to XPS to older laptops.. Never had issues with drivers these days. Even on my desktop PC, I threw in a USB wifi card from 2009. Guess what, it worked straight away with no issues.

Comment: You should try it out first with Wubi, and avoid wiping your Dell disk.  You'll probably find enough driver annoyances that you'll want to go back.

Comment: Ok so turns out I tried the Live USB version on my laptop. It had no internet! I'm not even sure on how to check which other drivers may be missing.

Comment: I got rid of my Dell partition the day I got my latop. Formatted it with a clean install of Windows 8 at the time and when Windows 10 came out I did a clean install of that via USB. I do clean installs on it all the time. I'll probably just wipe the entire drive and only load Ubuntu and see what I can get working or not working and go from there. Hopefully I can get Win10 in a VM working. Otherwise if all else fails I'll pull out my Win10 USB and start again. No biggy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Dell  XPS 13 9343](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201410-15913/) is a certified Ubuntu Laptop. You can install it without mayor issues, with drivers and etc.

**Quick note**: Most drivers - minus Nvida drivers - are already in the kernel. In some cases like nvidia, the company behind the drivers don't allow adding there drivers in an Operating System. You would have to pay Nvidia a hefty some, to get the drivers loaded in.

But, 99% of the time - from my experience - you don't have to download any drivers, except nvidia drivers. I haven't downloaded them in years, I use the open source nvidia drivers, and I can play games reasonably well.

here is an excerpt from that page:

---

> The Dell XPS 13 9343 laptop with the components described below has
>   been awarded the status of certified pre-install for Ubuntu. Please
>   note that for pre-installed systems:
>
> ```
> The system is available in some regions with a special image of Ubuntu pre-installed by the manufacturer. It takes advantage of the
> ```
>
> hardware features for this system and may include additional software.
>   You should check when buying the system whether this is an option.
>       Standard images of Ubuntu may not work at all on the system or may not work well, though Canonical and computer manufacturers will try to
>   certify the system with future standard releases of Ubuntu.
>
> Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit
>
> Pre-installed by manufacturer Certification notes
>
> Fixes
>
> ```
> The pre-install version of Ubuntu contained some bugs that were later on fixed through online updates. To check how to solve some of
> ```
>
> those issues you can visit Dell's knowledge base for this model
>   (http://search.euro.dell.com/results.aspx?c=uk&cs=ukbsdt1&l=en&s=bsd&cat=sup&k=XPS+13+%289343%29+Ubuntu)
>
> BIOS
>       Dell: X33 (UEFI)
>
> Hardware summary
>
> This system was tested with these key components: Processor
>
> Intel Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5###U CPU @ 2.00GHz Video
>
> Intel Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics Wireless
>
> Broadcom BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter Hardware details
>   Audio
>
> Intel Broadwell-U Audio Controller
>
> Intel Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
>
> Intel Unknown BIOS
>
> Dell X33 Bluetooth
>
> Broadcom BCM20702A0 Board
>
> Dell 0144P8 Capture
>
> Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Integrated_Webcam_HD Cardreader
>
> Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5249 PCI Express Card Reader
>   Chassis
>
> Dell Laptop Disk
>
> Unknown Toshiba THNSNJ128G8NU M.2 2280 128GB Efi
>
> EFI v2.31 American Megatrends Keyboard
>
> Unknown AT Translated Set 2 keyboard Other
>
> Unknown Dell WMI hotkeys
>
> Unknown HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3
>
> Unknown HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7
>
> Unknown HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8
>
> Unknown HDA Intel PCH Headphone Mic
>
> Unknown Lid Switch
>
> Unknown Power Button
>
> Unknown Sleep Button
>
> Unknown Video Bus
>
> Intel Broadwell-U Camarillo Device
>
> Intel Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI
>
> Intel Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
>
> Intel Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1
>
> Intel Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller
>
> Intel Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1
>
> Intel Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller
>
> Broadcom Unknown
>
> Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>
> Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>
> Intel Unknown Processor
>
> Intel Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5###U CPU @ 2.00GHz System
>
> Dell XPS 13 9343 Touchpad
>
> Unknown SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad Usb
>
> Intel Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller
>
> Intel Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller Video
>
> Intel Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics Wireless
>
> Broadcom BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter

Comment: I am guessing that the 15" developer edition hasn't come out yet because they are waiting for 16.04LTS?

Comment: I don't even know what you mean by any of that? Sorry! Can you please explain what you mean to me? Thanks matey.

Comment: I'm assuming the version of Ubuntu the Dell could of come pre-loaded with is a modifed version of 14.04 LTS?